# Using Samba with Linux user without tdbsam

Tags: linux, centos, samba, authentication

Is it possible to set Samba security in user mode, then have Samba use user/password which exists in Linux (passwd,shadow file)?
In the `smb.conf`, there is a line that says Samba to use `tdbsam` for `passdb`. How can I configure Samba for all users without use command `smbpasswd` for each one?
i want to have on athentication for some things like ftp, samba, ...

Comment: Not if you want want compatibility with anything after Windows 98.

Comment: my samba client use only window XP and Windows Seven